# office365/azure oauth using delegated user id

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory

My goal is to write some code to enable an Office 365 user to access files in OneDrive for business via REST API. I have registered an application in Azure AD (Web App/single tenant) and have a redirect URI to receive the OAuth token. I want to use the "delegated user identity with OAuth" scenario. To see how it works, I use the "Office 365 OAuth Sandbox" here: https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/. When I "Authorize using own account" and enter any valid Office 365 user credentials, I get an access token back. When I replace the client ID and redirect URI in the authorization URL with the info of my registered app, I can only get the token when I enter a user registered in my app (otherwise I get an error 50012 during sign-in). What do I have to change in my configuration to allow any Office 365 user to get an authorization token (like the Sandbox does) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark your web application as multitenant, or Azure AD will constrain all callers to be from the tenant in which you provisioned the application.
Take a look at https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet for an example of a web app that is multitenant and invokes a Microsoft API. Note that you don't necessarily need to validate issues as shown in the sample, just do what makes sense for your scenario (which might mean even not validating).

Comment: That did it. Thanks a ton. I imagine others will find this useful too.

Comment: My pleasure! In that case, would you mind marking the above as answer? Thanks :)